# AngularJS - html elements injected from controller are being wrapped in quotes/treated as strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have a simple user status dropdown, such as:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle">
   {{userStatus}}
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li data-ng-click="SwitchStatus('Online')"><i class="fa fa-circle text-green2 pr5"></i> Online</a></li>
    <li data-ng-click="SwitchStatus('Busy')"><i class="fa fa-circle text-red2 pr5"></i> Busy</li>
    <li data-ng-click="SwitchStatus('Away')"><i class="fa fa-circle text-orange2 pr5"></i> Away</li>
</ul>
```

And the controller has this:

```
var userStatuses = {
    online: '<i class="fa fa-circle text-green2 pr5"></i>',
    busy: "<i class='fa fa-circle text-red2 pr5'></i>",
    away: "<i class='fa fa-circle text-orange2 pr5'></i>"
};

$scope.userStatus = userStatuses.online; // default online
```

Why does it inject the HTML into the page like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle">
    "<i class='fa fa-circle text-green2 pr5'></i>"
</a>
```

What can I do so that it injects it as an HTML element and not a string?

Also, it's obvious what I'm trying to achieve, and I have just started with angular, so feel free to point me in another direction. I want to eventually incorporate advanced logic when the different statuses are selected.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that specific case I would use ng-class instead of pasting HTML in the template.

AngularJS isn't jquery.

see:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle">
  <i class='fa fa-circle pr5' ng-class="{'text-green2': userStatuses.online, 'text-red2': userStatuses.busy, 'text-orange2': userStatuses.away}"></i>
</a>
```

and the JavaScript

```
var userStatuses = {
  online: true,
  busy: false,
  away: false
};
scope.userStatuses = userStatuses;
```

Hope this whas helpfull.
Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you. I will use this. I'm still curious however, to understand why it was injected as HTML?

Comment: Speaking of your jQuery comment, this has been the biggest struggle for me so far is doing things the "Angular Way"... I've only been at this a few days.

Comment: It's a js string, not an HTML element, if you could paste a string as HTML just like that, the model's field couldn't have characters like "<" or ">", or the view would all be messed up.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, Angular won't render HTML in a `ng-bind` or similar directives to prevent XSS. If you want to render HTML as actual HTML, you should be using the `ng-bind-html` directive. That said, this answer solves this problem better than mine.

Comment: @SebastianGabrielVinci Ah, you beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you all. This is very helpful in conquering this learning curve!

Answer (score 0):

This is a use-case for `ng-bind-html`. Angular doesn't like inserting HTML unless explicitly told to do so, so as to prevent XSS vulnerabilities.

Your dropdown should look like:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" ng-bind-html="userStatus"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I think a better way would be to keep your html out of your controller and try using ng-class to change the class of your icon based on the userStatus object:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle">
   <i class="fa fa-circle pr5"
      ng-class="{{ 'text-green2' : userStatus.online,
                   'text-red2' : userStatus.away,
                   'text-orange2': userStatus.busy }}">
   </i>
</a>
```

In the controller, skip the `var` declaration you're using and do this

```
$scope.userStatus = userStatus;
```